# Cauchy-integral-formula

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

In our lecture, we hat the following Cauchy-integral-theorem (CIT):

> Let $f$ be a function that is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the disk $\mathcal K(z_0,M)$ with radius M and centre $z_0$. Then $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(z_0,M)}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\ \text{d}z$$ $\underline{Note}:$ $\gamma(z_0,M)$ is the boundary of the disk with radius $M$ and centre $z_0$

Now I saw some examples of the CIT like this:

> Calculate $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z+i}\ \text{d}z$
>
> For $z_0=-i$ and $f(z)=\sin(z)$ we obtain with the CIT $$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\sin(z)}{z+i}\ \text{d}z = 2\pi if(-i)=2\pi i\sin(-i) $$

What I don't understand here is that the disk in the integral to be calculated is $|z|=2 \Leftrightarrow \gamma(0,2)$, so $z_0$ actually would need to be $0$. I don't see why the example is consistent with the CIF. If the integral would be $\int_{\gamma(-i,2)}\frac{\sin(z)}{z+i}\ \text{d}z$ instead of $\int_{\gamma(0,2)}\frac{\sin(z)}{z+i}\ \text{d}z$, everything would be clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(z_0,M)}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\ \text{d}z$

is only a special case of the $CIT$.

More general we have

$f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(z_0,M)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}\ \text{d}z$  for all $w$ such that $|w-z_0|<M$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a picture to illustrate Fred's answer:

[image]